# Javascript instance context prototype

Tags: javascript, this

Sorry for not so good topic title. Don't know how to name it.

I need a help with this example, I'm totaly lost.

So when function fillView called it's all good, but second time when its called on re-size it just doesn't work, because  inside render functions 'this' defines a Window, but not a instance of localClass. I need a explanation how to figure out this problem. Please write a example.

```
(function ($) { 
var localClass = function(options) {
    this.a = 123;
};

localClass.prototype.render = function() {
    console.log(this.a);
}

$.fn.fillView = function(options){
    var view = new localClass(options);
    view.render(); //this prints to console 123

    $(window).resize(view.render); //this doesn't print 123 
                                     because 'this' is now - Window

    }
})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
$(window).resize(view.render);
```

with

```
$(window).resize(function(){view.render()});
```

If you target only new browser (that is you don't need to be compatible with IE8) you can also use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) :

```
$(window).resize(view.render.bind(view));
```

---

How it works :

**1)** When you pass a function, you merely set the value of another property to that function. That's like doing

```
var f = view.render.
```

And when this function is called, it is called for example like this :

```
f();
```

It might be more clear then that `this`, in the function, has no reason to be `view`. It would be, here, in fact `window`. To be more precise, `this`, in the function, is not the initial "owner" of a function but is the receiver, which depends on how you **call** the function.

In fact, it might have been another object : if you execute

```
f.call(someObject)
```

then `this` in `f` (which is `render`) would be `someObject`.

**2)** But when you pass a function which is

```
var f = function(){ view.render() }
```

then it doesn't matter how you call `f` because `render` is called with `view` as receiver.

**3)** There are other solutions : `bind` or `$.proxy` both build a new function which embeds yours but ensure `this` is always the object you pass.

Comment: You could also use [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) as a substitute for `bind` like this: `$(window).resize($.proxy(view.render, view))`

Comment: @kalley Yes. Personally I prefer to avoid using a jQuery only solution to a generic problem but that's a personal preference. That's why you should not have deleted your own answer.

Comment: omg, you owned. it worked. HOW??  can you explained how it worked? For me it doesn't make any sense. I need to understand. :/